# Where exactly does KIE Workbench create a project?

Tags: maven, wildfly-10, kie, kie-workbench

Before anyone starts downvoting this question, I tried Googling this with *all* combinations of the words "kie", "project", "where", "location", "workbench", "pom", "source", "files" and I did not get one single answer.

I am running `kie-wb.war` on Wildfly 10.0.0. I just want a simple answer to a simple question: **When I create a new project on KIE workbench, where does it create the source files?**

I am sorry if I seem rude, but KIE Workbench is really getting on my nerves now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the projects are created in wildFly_HOME/bin/.niogit directorty. You can clone this repository into eclipse and use eclipse plugin to develop rules/processes.

Answer (score 0):

On JBOSS You can also change this default location mentioned by @Abhijit in your standalone or domain .xml file by setting a system property for niogit: org.uberfire.nio.git.dir

see: [1]: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.systemproperties

Just as a side note on the files you will find in the .niogit location; note that the files will not be readable so you will have to use something like

```
git cat-file -p <object_name>
```

where object name is the concatenation of the object folder name and object filename

see [1]: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects